# Can I get last Invoke payload using TXID in Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I wanna get invoke payload using last txID

this is success invoke result example

```
...
"payload" : { 
    "result" : 200,
    "msg" : "Success",
    "data" : {
        "id": "123321"
    }
    "txId" : "52811cc0fc2bc0f03d45a1a28a70f96352e9a762111b165651fb8bbbedk"
}
```

can I get this same result using txid(52811cc0fc2bc0f03d45a1a28a70f96352e9a762111b165651fb8bbbedk)?

Comment: Can you explain a little more clearly exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: I wanna get result, msg and data when i succeed invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the function [queryTransaction()](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Channel.html#queryTransaction__anchor), inside the [transaction](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/global.html#Transaction) you can get input/output keys, status, message, ...

Comment: thx!
I can get information in payload and message in response. right?